# How do I exit an Array.forEach loop early?

Tags: javascript, loops, foreach

I'm working on a homework problem using JavaScript. I have a solution that currently works, but I am sure that it is not the most efficient way to do it. I am iterating over an array to check if ***any*** element meets a certain condition. But there doesn't seem to be a way to exit the `forEach()` function early. In other languages, I have used `break` to quit a forEach loop early. Does something similar exist in JavaScript?

My code (simplified for this question):

```
let conditionMet = false;

numbers.forEach((number) => {
  if (number % 3 === 0) {
    conditionMet = true;
    // break; <-- does not work!
  }
});
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Rather than using `Array.forEach`, you can use `Array.some` ([see docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)). This function iterates over the elements of the array, checking to see if ***any*** element meets a certain condition. If an element is found that meets the condition, the function stops iteration, and returns `true`. If not, the function returns `false`. This means that you can also skip the step of initializing `conditionMet` to `false`.

Your code can therefore be simplified as:

```
let conditionMet = numbers.some(number => (number % 3 === 0));
```

Comment: Thanks -- this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can’t break .foreach() loop unless through an exception
So you can choose another tool like a simple for loop.